# How to edit 'A Call Comes In' voice webhook in Twilio through Python?

Tags: python, flask, twilio

How can I edit the 'A CALL COMES IN' webhook for a Twilio account through the Python/Flask API in Twilio to have this type of functionality?

```py
account_sid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
auth_token = 'your_auth_token'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

# example functionality:
# number = client.incoming_phone_numbers.list()[0]
# number.webhook.voice_a_call_comes_in = 'https://myurl.com'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the code below:

```
# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
# DANGER! This is insecure. See http://twil.io/secure

from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = 'ACdefg5dxxxxxxeeb8beaba1234567890'
auth_token = 'SECRET'

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

incoming_phone_number = client \
    .incoming_phone_numbers('PN0185dd75921b77441c0af9e9123456789') \
    .update(
         voice_url='https://example.com'
     )

print(incoming_phone_number.friendly_name)
```